# LINQ to XML Query not working as desired

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm having trouble with a LINQ to XML query in Visual Studio 2015 C#.net.  I'm writing a console application.  In the spirit of transparency, I am new to all of the above, so I may have a simple error that needs to be pointed out.  I've spent several hours reading examples to get this far.

XML data set:

```
<inv-balance>
  <item ccard-charge-percent="3.8" color-code="51" description="g200 BLACK XL" gtin="00821780001021" price="$2.83" size-code="6" special-expiry="04/23/17" special-price="$1.97" style-code="g200">
    <whse code="CC">69666</whse>
    <whse code="KC">30613</whse>
    <whse code="GD">63661</whse>
    <whse code="PH">98920</whse>
    <whse code="TD">54505</whse>
    <whse code="FO">36127</whse>
    <whse code="MA">88852</whse>
    <whse code="CD">19212</whse>
    <whse code="CN">62769</whse>
    <whse code="WA">15232</whse>
    <whse code="D4">0</whse>
    <whse code="DB">0</whse>
    <whse code="DD">0</whse>
    <whse code="DL">0</whse>
    <whse code="DR">0</whse>
    <whse code="DU">0</whse>
    <whse code="DP">0</whse>
    <whse code="D2">0</whse>
    <whse code="DT">0</whse>
    <whse code="DK">0</whse>
    <whse code="DO">0</whse>
    <whse code="NC">0</whse>
    <whse code="DZ">0</whse>
    <whse code="DS">0</whse>
    <whse code="DI">0</whse>
    <whse code="DQ">0</whse>
    <whse code="D1">0</whse>
    <whse code="DE">0</whse>
    <whse code="DV">0</whse>
    <whse code="DN">0</whse>
    <whse code="D8">0</whse>
  </item>
</inv-balance>
```

My code:

```
XDocument rawxml = XDocument.Load(url);
var things = from r in rawxml.Descendants("inv-balance")
             select new
             {
                 price = r.Element("item").Attribute("price"),
                 saleprice = (string)r.Element("item").Attribute("special-price") ?? "none",
                 expdate = (string)r.Element("item").Attribute("special-expiry") ?? "none"
             };

var inv = (from whinv in rawxml.Descendants("item")
           select new
           {
               whse = whinv.Element("whse").Attribute("code").Value,
               qty = whinv.Element("whse").Value
           }).ToList();

foreach (var r in things)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Regular Price: " + r.price);
    if (r.saleprice != "none")
        Console.WriteLine("Sale Price: " + r.saleprice + " On sale through " + r.expdate);
    Console.WriteLine("Inventory Available:");
    foreach (var whinv in inv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Location: " + whinv.whse + " | " + whinv.qty);
    }
}
```

This image is the result

[image]

What I want to do is retrieve the inventory from all of the warehouses.... preferably CC, KC, GD, PH, TD, FO, MA, CD , CN, WA the others never will have inventory.

Right now it's only pulling the first warehouse code.  I've tried filtering by the attribue with no dice.  The XML is not malformed, my paste in here is wierd for some reason... it should be whse code="xx".

I'd appreciate any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong.  My eventual goal will be to write this to a database, but for now I'm stepping through being able to display the data.

Comment: If I was writing this query in SQL it would go something like:
   select code,qty from whse where code in ('cc','kc','gd','ph','td','fo','ma','cd','cn','wa')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var codes = new List<string> { "CC", "KC", "GD", "PH", "TD", "FO", "MA", "CD", "CN", "WA" };

var inv = (from whinv in rawxml.Descendants("item").Elements("whse")
           where codes.Contains(whinv.Attribute("code").Value)
           select new
           {
               whse = whinv.Attribute("code").Value,
               qty = whinv.Value
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Not quite.  I want to extract both the code and the value of the node.  I only want to do this if the code is one of 7 specific codes.

Another way to look at this is that I only care about the inventory of certain warehouses.  So if it's CC, KC, GD, PH, TD, FO, MA, CD, CN, or WA I need to grab that value.  For some products one of those warehouses may be out of stock and I need to know that.  Other warehouses will always be zero stock and I want to ignore them.

Right now my problem is that my code only returns CC and nothing else.

Comment: It would be more efficient to filter in my query, but I can also do this in c#.

I've contemplated a different approach using a function where I grab the warehouses I want one at a time, I'm just concerned that this isn't very efficient when you scale it up to 20,000 or 30,000 products and duplicate it to a couple of vendors.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly.  Thank you.  :)

However, I want to make sure I understand what you did.  After all, I'm grateful for the solution, but I want to understand why it works.

So the first part looks simple enough:
- Put the "target" values in a list, which makes it easy to compare the results to.

It looks like one of my mistakes was that I was not low enough in the XML tree.

And then it looks like I needed to push the results to a list using the ToList Method (I think that's what it is called).